# Como implementar una APPde llamadas mediante sip.js y cordova-plugin-iosrtc contra una PBX FreeSwitch?

Tags: ios, ionic, cordova

Necesito vuestra ayuda!! Urgente!!

Estoy desarrollando una app híbrida con Ionic JS/AngularJS basada en webrtc para realizar llamadas/videollamadas . La aplicación utiliza la librería sip.js para las llamadas. La parte servidora es una PBX FreeSwitch. Para tener en IOS WebRtc,estamos usando el plugin cordova-plugin-iosrtc.  Cuando intento realizar o recibir llamadas,la aplicación lanza errores usando el plugin cordova-plugin-iosrtc de las dos maneras que se puede conjuntamente con sip sip.js

A) MODO A cordova-plugin-iosrtc Trabajando con el peer connection ....

telephoneService.js (Angular JS)

```
var pc = new cordova.plugins.iosrtc.RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: []
});

cordova.plugins.iosrtc.getUserMedia(
  // constraints
  { audio: true, video: true },
  // success callback
  function (stream) {
    console.log('got local MediaStream: ', stream);
    pc.addStream(stream);
  },
  // failure callback
  function (error) {
    console.error('getUserMedia failed: ', error);
  }
);

var sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions = {

                constraints: {
                    audio: audioId,
                    video: videoId
                },


                media: {
                    local: {
                      audio: document.getElementById('localAudio')
                    },
                    remote: {
                      audio: document.getElementById('remoteAudio')
                    }
                },


            extraHeaders: extraHeaders

            }

}

userAgent.invite('sipusertocall', sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions);
```

Error:

> undefined is not a objetc evaluating
>   'environment.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia' (sip.js lib)

B) MODO B cordova.plugins.iosrtc.registerGlobals(); usamos iosrtc plugin con webrtc nativo (navigator.mediaDevice.getUserMedia(), ....)

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
 function (stream) {
    console.log('got local MediaStream: ', stream);

    window.stream = stream;
  },
  // failure callback
  function (error) {
    console.error('getUserMedia failed: ', error);
  }
)

var sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions = {

                constraints: {
                    audio: audioId,
                    video: videoId
                },


                media: {
                    local: {
                      audio: document.getElementById('localAudio')
                    },
                    remote: {
                      audio: document.getElementById('remoteAudio')
                    }
                },


            extraHeaders: extraHeaders

        }

userAgent.invite('sipusertocall', sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions);
```

App recibe el siguiente  error mediante sip.js desde la PBX: Failed:WebRTC Error

La app recibe también el siguiente error al mismo tiempo: "setLocalDescription() must be called with a RTCSessionDescription instance as first argument"

Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: traduce tu pregunta, estas en la versión en español de SO, de otro modo terminará cerrada

Comment: traduce el título también

Comment: Hecho! Perdón por el error. Gracias!